# What's the best practice with git for multiple language implementations?

Tags: git, github

So I have a few private git repositories that are different language implementations (Python, Java, etc.) of an algorithm.  Each implementation is functionally identical, performing the same steps and giving the same output.  Currently, these are separate repos, but I was wondering if I shouldn't unify them into one repo, with directories indicating the language, like:

```
  master
     - java
     - python
     - ruby
```

I could use a git-repo combine command to preserve the history, so that's not an issue.  I was just curious as to the best practice regarding this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this same question with Mercurial, and an algorithm ([COBS](http://www.stuartcheshire.org/papers/COBSforToN.pdf)) that I wanted to implement in [C](http://bitbucket.org/cmcqueen1975/cobs-c/) and [Python](http://bitbucket.org/cmcqueen1975/cobs-python/).

Eventually I decided to split it into separate repositories (even though the Python implementation included a C extension that had similar code to the plain C implementation). My reasoning came down to:

- I wanted to have independent version numbering of the implementations, and independent releases.

  - [`git describe`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) is a nice feature to identify a version based on the latest annotated tag. With just one implementation in the repository, `git describe` usage is simple. But if different implementations with separate version numbers are in the one repository, then `git describe` usage becomes more complicated, needing use of the `--match` option to limit to tags with a given prefix. e.g. `git describe --match "python*"`
- The way Python modules are typically organised ([Python module packaging best-practices](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/)), it made more sense to me to keep the Python implementation separate and self-contained.
- All else being equal, I tend to favour more fine-grained modularity.

Comment: I've heard the fine-grained modularity with respect to git repos, and it makes sense.  I'm going to push my private repos to github soon, so I wanted to follow best practice, if one exists.

Answer (score 6):

It's a tough call. Probably what's "best" will just boil down to personal preference and/or the specifics of the circumstances at hand.

On the one hand, each directory isn't technically "related" to any other. While they do implement the same algorithm, none depends on any of the others (so from a pure source code point of view, they are unrelated). Usually, unrelated things are best left in separate repos (for reasons identified in Craig McQueen's answer).

However, because they *do* implement the same algorithm, you may find that if you need to change the algorithm, you'll need to make very similar changes to all of the directories. In such a case, it *might* make sense to make all of the changes as a single commit. Let's say you decide the algorithm needs to support "virtual dinglehoppers". You'd add that support to each directory and make a single commit whose message is "Add support for virtual dinglehoppers". This is nice because if you later decide that adding virtual dinglehopper support was *bad*, you can now revert just a single commit. The alternative is to make three separate commits to three separate repositories and then revert three separate commits from three separate repositories.

Again, it's a tough call. I don't think there's a clear-cut, hard-and-fast rule to go by.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Dan.  You make some good points, especially the one regarding changing the same aspect of the algorithm in all language implementations.  I agree -- it's a tough call, and from what I've gathered, there's not a definitive best practice out there.